# Error: 1408A0C1:ssl routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, indy

I create a DataSnap REST Server with the Wizard for a 3-Tier application having two connections:

- One by TCP/IP Port: 211 and it works properly.
- Second connection by HTTP Port 8080 and this not works.When I launch a simple https://localhost:8080/ from the Navigator, Launch a debugger error shown in the attached file.

The Wizard has created the Procedure:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  LIOHandleSSL: TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL;
begin
  FServer := TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.Create(Self);
  LIOHandleSSL := TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Create(FServer);
  LIOHandleSSL.SSLOptions.CertFile := '';
  LIOHandleSSL.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := '';
  LIOHandleSSL.SSLOptions.KeyFile := '';
  LIOHandleSSL.OnGetPassword := OnGetSSLPassword;
  FServer.IOHandler := LIOHandleSSL;
end;
```

[image: Error Launching from Navigator]

Comment: Are you trying to set up an SSL connection without specifying the Server SSL Certificate? If there is no certificate then it makes sense that no shared cipher can be found! If you leave out the whole SSL part it will probably work?

Comment: Even the anonymous cipher suites (which cause the server to *not* send a certificate) have values reserved to them by IANA. See [Transport Layer Security (TLS) Parameters](http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml).

Comment: Usually, 8443 is the alternate port to use for HTTPS, not HTTP. Can you confirm you are using HTTPS on 8080? The trouble shooting tool here is OpenSSL. See what it returns and add it to your question. Try `openssl s_client -connect localhost:8080`. Try it with the `-ssl3` option, and with the `tls1` option. Also try it with `-cipher "aDH"` in case your server is configured without a certificate.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind attention.  I send you the answers I received from SSLOpen of your commands.

Comment: [link]('OpenSSL> s_client -connect localhost:8080
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(000000E4)
7944:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake fa
ilure:.\ssl\s23_clnt.c:769:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 361 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
---
error in s_client')

Comment: I tried with other options you told me and the answer was like this:

Comment: OpenSSL> s_client -connect localhost:8080 -ssl3
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(00000178)
7944:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:.
\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1456:SSL alert number 40
7944:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:.\ssl\s3
_pkt.c:644:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated

Comment: SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1423560254
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
error in s_client

Comment: Birger, you are right . . . The wizard created a HTTPS connection by means of OpenSSL and I need only HTTP connection.  I omitted the option for HTTPS and it wroks properly.

Comment: Thank you very much to All of you. . . . :):):):)

Comment: @Blaise - please put the additional information in your question. Please do so by clicking *Edit*. Please refrain from putting the information in the comments. As you can see, its nearly impossible to read.